# How to stream youtube audio with ffmpeg discord bot

Tags: c#, .net-core, ffmpeg, discord, dsharp+

so at the moment I got my disord bot to play audio from a filepath with this code

```
   var transmit = vnc.GetTransmitSink();

        var pcm = ConvertAudioToPcm(filepath);

        await pcm.CopyToAsync(transmit);

        Console.WriteLine(duration);
    }


    private Stream ConvertAudioToPcm(string filePath)
    {
        var ffmpeg = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "ffmpeg",
            Arguments = $@"-i ""{filePath}"" -ac 2 -f s16le -ar 48000 pipe:1",
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false
        });
        return ffmpeg.StandardOutput.BaseStream;
    }
```

With YoutubeExplode I am able to get a stream from the URL but when I CopyToAsync I get very loud static on the discord bot.
Does anybody have an idea on how to stream audio properly from a youtube URL using ffmpeg?
Thank you in advance

EDIT:
Got it to work with this  code to create PCM stream, but it doesn't use youtube explode, it uses youtube-dl.exe

```
 private Stream ConvertURLToPcm(string url)
    {
        string args = $"/C youtube-dl --ignore-errors -o - {url} | ffmpeg -err_detect ignore_err -i pipe:0 -ac 2 -f s16le -ar 48000 pipe:1";
        var ffmpeg = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "cmd.exe",
            Arguments = args,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false
        });
        return ffmpeg.StandardOutput.BaseStream;
    }
```